# How to get any useful information when JDeb fails to create a Debian package?

Tags: java, ant, package, debian, deb

I use [JDeb](https://github.com/tcurdt/jdeb) for a few days. I try to create a Debian package for my Java based first person shooter. I use Ant as a build tool. I put this line into my Ant script at the very beginning:

```
<taskdef name="pure-java-deb" classname="org.vafer.jdeb.ant.DebAntTask" classpath="lib/ant/jdeb-1.3.jar"/>
```

I try to use this library further:

```
<delete failonerror="false" file="${destdir}/control" />
    <echo file="${destdir}/control">
        <![CDATA[
        Package: ${project-unix-name}
        Version: 0
        Section: Games
        Priority: low
        Architecture: all
        Description: ${game-description}
        Maintainer: xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.fr

        ]]>
    </echo>
    <pure-java-deb destfile="${destdir}/${project-unix-name}.deb" control="${destdir}/control" verbose="true">
        <data src="${destdir}/${game-jar-filename}" type="file">
            <mapper type="perm" prefix="/usr/share/games/${project-unix-name}"/>
        </data>
    </pure-java-deb>
    <delete failonerror="false" file="${destdir}/control" />
```

I only get the following error message even when I set "verbose" to "true":
Failed to create the Debian package tuer/target/tuer.deb

BUILD FAILED
tuer/build.xml:463: Failed to create the Debian package tuer/target/tuer.deb

Is there a way of getting any information about the cause(s) of the failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse, go to the menu item "Window" -> "Show View" -> "Error Log". Then, double click on the line containing "Failure of Background Ant Build" and it shows the full stack trace.