# How to get useful information when JDeb fails to create a Debian package without using Eclipse

Tags: java, ant, debian, package, deb

The only message it shows, even when verbose=true is:

```
[deb] Creating debian package: /dir/packg.deb
[deb] Building data
[deb] Failed to create the Debian package /dir/packg.deb

BUILD FAILED
/dir/build.xml:80: Failed to create the Debian package /dir/packg.deb
```

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193364/how-to-get-any-useful-information-when-jdeb-fails-to-create-a-debian-package) but it only applies to Eclipse users.

If Eclipse has it, this file must be saved somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make ant be extra verbose by passing it the "-v" parameter. This will show the stack trace in the console.